# How infectious is herpes?

Tags: herpes, herpes-simplex

My grandparents both have facial herpes around their lips and I have just spent a weekend with them.

On arrival I was unaware of their conditions and therefore hugged them and allowed them to kiss me on the cheek.

Later in the weekend, I also gave a kiss to my grandma on her cheek and hugged them when saying goodbye with some skin in contact.

Their lips hardly came into contact with my cheek but I am still worried that I could have herpes.

I haven't noticed anything different about my skin on my face but my girlfriend wants me to get the test for herpes.

How likely is it for me to be infected with herpes considering what I have described above?

Comment: If you do not develop the lesions of herpes anywhere on your face (which is a sign that you have contracted the virus), you can rest assured you did not catch it.

Comment: It's worth spelling out that you should wash immediately afterwards, maybe even dab a little alcohol on your cheeks.  Plus, don't shave the area since that creates openings at the root of the hair follicles.